# assign memory location to register assembly

Tags: memory, assembly, x86, att

Let's say for example I have four specific memory addresses that each hold a 32-bit integer. How would you use assembly language to take the address and assign it register `%eax`?

Would it be `movl 0x12AED567, %eax`?

Comment: You mentioned four specific memory addresses. Then you asked, *...take **the** address...*. Which of the four are you referring to? Or any one of them? Normally, data locations you care about are labeled and you would refer to them by label when you want to refer to them. How a block of 4 items in memory are labeled depends upon what they are. If it's an array, it might all have one label at the lowest address. Or they might all have their own label.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is that simple. If you already have the addresses, just assign them to eax, I corrected your code a little :

```
mov 12AED567h, eax
```

But, if you want to get the addresses dynamically, you have to use **lea** instruction, next little program shows how :

```
.stack 100h
.data
my_number dd A01Ch
.code          
;INITIALIZE DATA SEGMENT.
  mov  ax,@data
  mov  ds,ax

;GET THE MEMORY ADDRESS OF MY_NUMBER, NOT THE NUMBER ITSELF.  
  lea  eax, my_number    

;FINISH THE PROGRAM PROPERLY.
  mov  ax,4c00h
  int  21h
```

Is this what you were looking for?

By the way, this is 8086 assembler with Intel's syntax.

Comment: Normally, if you have data, it would be labeled and you would use the label, not a literal hex address.

Comment: I agree, Lurker, in that case you use LEA to get the variable's address.

Comment: Yes this answered my question. Thank you very much.

Comment: Well, if you want, you may accept the answer (as the right one), or upvoted it (or both!).